# Anaconda/Python/VSCode: vscode editor doesn't recognize installed packages

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I'm trying to use VS Code for python in an Anaconda environment. I have (after some googling and travail) gotten it using my custom environment. However, pylint and the editor don't recognize the installed netifaces in the environment.

The environment (billh) is being loaded:

[image: environment from VSC]

The errors from python are shown here:

[image: PyLint errors]

Oddly, importing from ipython running in the built-in terminal does work:

[image]

This was newly installed today, via Anaconda.  Here's the version info

[image]

Comment: This appear to be the same as this (unanswered) question, but with greater detail:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131620/vscode-did-not-recognize-my-installed-python-packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't that the extension can't find the `netifaces` package, it's that Pylint can't. Make sure that the Pylint you are having the extension run for you is installed into the same conda environment that you are running from (e.g. make sure you didn't set `python.linting.pylintPath` to something outside of your conda environment). Also make sure that ipython is from the same environment as well (e.g. you are using a conda environment and launched the terminal with the `Python: Create Terminal` command).